# Numbers Appearing blank

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a text-based RPG kinda game and whenever I try and print the damage done or hp or other things, it sometimes appears blank ( just a bigger space in between the strings) I'm using replit to run and edit my code. In addidtion to this (and this isnt that big of an issue) Whenever its printing out the players HP then it comes to something like 9.7999999999999, why is this?

LOGIC AND CALCULATION CODE BELOW

```
#Imports

from player import Player
from items import Item
from spells import Spells
from monsters import Monster
from gameplay import Fight
#Creating spells
# Type, Name, Damage, Cost
#Below are buff spells
buff_A = Spells("buff", "Buff", 1.1, 5)
buff_B = Spells("buff", "Stronger Buff", 1.3, 15)
buff_C = Spells("buff", "Strongest Buff", 1.5, 50)
#Below Are heal spells
heal_A = Spells("heal", "Heal", 5, 10)
heal_B = Spells("heal", "Stronger Heal", 20, 30)
heal_C = Spells("heal", "Strongest Heal", 50, 100)
#Creating Items
#Type, Name, Description, Amount
potion = Item("potion", "Health Potion", "Heals you for 10 HP", 10)
elixir = Item("elixir", "Mana Potion", "Regains 15 MP", 15)
#Assiging Variables For Player
player_spells = [buff_A, heal_A]
player_items = [potion, elixir]
#Creating player
#NAME, HP, MP, ATK, DEF, SPELLS, ITEMS
player = Player("Nathan", 10, 20, 5, 5, player_spells, player_items)
#Creating monster
cricket = Monster("Cricket", 3, 3, 7)
enemies = [cricket]
#Fight Setup
fighting = True
#gameplay
fight1 = Fight(player, cricket)
running = True
def player_hurt(enemy):
  edamage = enemy.damage_dealt()
  player.take_dmg(edamage)
  print("You have taken " + str(edamage) + " damage")
  print(str(player.hp) + " / " + str(player.maxhp))
#action = input("Please select an action, Attack, Magic, Items ")
while running:
  print("1 for attack etc.")
  choice = input(player.actions)
  list_chooser = int(choice) - 1
#ATTACK CHOOSE
  if list_chooser == 0:
    dmg = player.generate_dmg()
    enemies[0].damage_taken(dmg)
    print("You did " + str(dmg) + " damage")
    player_hurt(enemies[0])
    if cricket.hp == 0:
      print("You have killed the cricket")
      running = False
      #Add Exp element here later
#MAGIC CHOOSE
  if list_chooser == 1:
    print("Choose 1 for first spell, etc. ")
    magic_choice = input()
    magic_choice_real = int(magic_choice) - 1
    if magic_choice_real == 0:
      print("idek how to code this")
    if magic_choice_real == 1:
      if player.mp < heal_A.cost:
        print("Insufficient mana")
      if player.mp >= heal_A.cost:
        player.heal(heal_A.dmg)
        print("You healed for " + str(heal_A.dmg))
        player.mp -= heal_A.cost
        print("You lost " + str(heal_A.cost) + " mana")
        player_hurt(cricket)
```

PLAYER CODE BELOW

```
# IMPORTS

import random

#CLASS PLAYER

class Player():
  def __init__(self, name, hp, mp, atk, df, magic, items):
    self.maxhp = hp
    self.hp = hp
    self.maxmp = mp
    self.mp = mp
    self.atklow = atk - 2
    self.atkhigh = atk + 2
    self.df = df - 100
    self.dfc = df / 100
    self.magic = magic
    self.items = items
    self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic", "Items", "Stats"]
    self.name = name

#Dealing Damage
    
  def generate_dmg(self):  
    return random.randrange(self.atklow, self.atkhigh)
    
#Taking Damage
    
  def take_dmg(self, dmg):
    self.hp -= dmg * self.dfc
    if self.hp < 0:
      self.hp = 0
    return self.hp

  #Healing

  def heal(self, dmg):
    self.hp += dmg
    if self.hp > self.maxhp:
      self.hp = self.maxhp

  #Returning HP Values

  def get_hp(self):
    return self.hp

  def get_maxhp(self):
    return self.maxhp

  #Mana Cost Logic

  def reduce_mp(self, cost):
    self.mp -= cost

  #Actions
  def get_stats(self):
    print("HP")
    print(self.hp)
    print("--")
    print(self.maxhp)
    print("")
    print("MP")
    print(self.mp)
    print("--")
    print(self.maxmp)
    print("")
    print("ATK")
    print(self.atklow + self.atkhigh)
    print("DEF")
    print(self.dfc)
```

MONSTER CODE BELOW

```
import random
class Monster:
  def __init__(self, name, atk, df, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.atk = atk
    self.hp = hp
    self.maxhp = hp
    self.atklow = self.atk - 2
    self.atkhigh = self.atk + 2
  def damage_dealt(self):
    return random.randrange(self.atklow, self.atkhigh)
  def damage_taken(self, dmg):
    self.hp -= dmg  
    if self.hp < 0:
      self.hp = 0
    return self.hp
  def get_hp(self):
    return self.hp
  def get_maxhp(self):
    return self.maxhp
```

SPELLS

```
import random
class Spells:
  def __init__(self, type, name, dmg, cost):
    self.type = type
    self.name = name
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.cost = cost

  def generate_dmg(self):
    low = self.dmg + 3
    high = self.dmg - 3
    return random.randrange(low, high)
```

ITEMS

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, type, name, desc, amount):
    self.type = type
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc
    self.amount = amount
```

GAMEPLAY(not sure if this is gonna be used)

```
import random
import os
class Fight:
  def __init__(self, enemy, player):
    self.enemy = enemy
    self.player = player
    self.playert = True
    self.enemyt = False
    self.player_action_allowed = False
    self.player_action_allowed = False
  def turns(self):
    if self.playert == True:
      self.player_action_allowed = True
      self.enemyt = True
      self.playert = False
    elif self.enemyt == True:
      enemy_action_allowed = True
      player_action_allowed = False
      playert = True
      enemyt = False
    else:
      playert = True
```

Comment: Which lines are printing as blank?

Comment: As for the HP, this is just how float division works. It will look prettier if you use formatting, e.g. (assuming you want nothing after the decimal): print(f'{self.hp:.0f}')

Comment: The printing as blank pattern is really inconsistent but its mainly on the "you dealt x damage" and "The cricket dealt x damage to you"

Comment: It's going to be hard to reproduce your issue without a full code example (esp. since you import from multiple files not shown above), and I suspect few users will want to look at the full code anyway. I suggest you try to create a minimal example that demonstrates your issue. You might even figure out the issue yourself in the process.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a problem with Replit itself, I added all of the other imports. Do you know of a good code editor that runs on the web?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error. So far, every time I run the code it prints the damage normally. As for editing, I can't recommend any web editors, since I do all my editing on my own machine using vim. I would generally expect a Python web editor to be a big buggy. Some popular IDEs that support Python are VSCode, Atom, Spyder, and Jupyter (which might have a web interface).